# Which testing method to use?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

First of all, I'm new to testing software. I suppose I'm rather green. Still for this project I need it to make sure all the calculations are done right. For the moment I'm using unit tests to test each module in C# to make sure it does what it should do.

I know about some different testing methods (Integration, unit testing), but I can't seemingly find any good book or reference material on testing in general. Most of em are to the point in one specific area (like unit testing). This sort of makes it really hard (for me) to get a good grasp on how to test your software the best, and which method to use.

For example, I'm using GUI elements as well, should I test those? Should I just test it by using it and then visually confirm all is in order? I do know it depends on whether it's critical or not, but at which point do you say "Let's not test that, because it's not really relevant/important"?

So a summary: How to choose which testing method is best, and where do you draw the line when you use the method to test your software?

Comment: which technology do you use? WPF/Winforms/ASP.net?

Comment: Winforms mostly, it's a desktop application. Also no real need for access to databases/internet. Just config files on the drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several kind of tests but imho the most important are unit test, component test, function test and end-to-end test.

- `Unit tests` checks if your classes works as intended.(JUnit). These tests are the base of your testing environment as these tells whether your methods works. Your goal is 100% coverage here as these are the most important part of your tests.
- `Component tests` checks how several class works together in your code. Component can be a lot of stuff in the code, but its basically more than unit testing, and less than function testing. The goal coverage is around 75%.
- `Function tests` are testing the actual functionalities you implement. For example, if you want a button that saves some input data to a database, that is a functionality of the program. That is what you test. The goal coverage here is around 50%.
- `End-to-end tests` are testing your whole application. These can be quite robust, and you likely cant and don't want to test everything, this test is here to check if the whole system works. The goal coverage is around 25%.

This is the order of importance too.

There is no such thing in these as "better" though. Any test you can run to check if your code works as intended is equally good.

You probably want most of your test automated: so you can test while you having a coffee break or your servers can test everything while you are away from work, then check the results in the morning.

GUI testing considered the hardest part of testing, and there are several tools that help you with that, for example Selenium for browser-GUI testing.
Several architectural patterns like Model-View-Presenter tries to separate the GUI part of the application because of this and work with as dumb GUI as possible to avoid errors in there. If you can successfully separate your graphic, you will be able to mock out the gui part of the application and simply left it out from most of the testing process.

For reference I suggest "Effective Software Testing" from Elfriede Dustin, but I'm not familiar with the books on the subject; there could be better ones.

Answer (score 0):

It realy depends on the software you need to test. If you are mostly interested in the logic behind (calculations) then you should write some integration tests that will test not just separate methods, but the workflow from start to finish, so try to emulate what typical user would do. I can hardly imagine user calling one particular method - most likely some specific sequence of methods. If the calculations are ok - then the chance is low that GUI will display it wrong. Besides automating GUI is time consuming process and it will require a lot of skill and energy to build it and maintain, as every simple change might brake everything. My advice is to start with writing integration tests with different values that will cover the most common scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is specific to the type of application you are involved in - WinForms
For GUI use MVC/MVP pattern. Avoid writing any code in the code behind file. This will allow you to unit test your UI code. When I say UI code it means you will be able to test your code which will be invoked when a button is clicked or any action that needs to be taken on an UI event occurrence.

You should be able to unit test each of your class files (except UI code). This will mainly focus on state based testing.

Also, you will be able to write interaction test cases for tests involving multiple class files. This should cover most of your flows.

So two things to focus on **State based testing** and **Interaction testing**.

Comment: So what you're suggesting is seperating the logic from the GUI, unittest the logic and just refer to the methode when the button is clicked (and give the info from the GUI through locals)?

I'm a bit unsure about Interaction testing, should I automate this (ala unit test), or try it myself (i.e. pretty much run through a testcase)? Or just call a public method for instance calculateThis() which has multiple methods from different classes?

None the less, great answer!

Comment: When I say interaction testing I don't actually mean automated UI testing. I am not a big fan of automated UI testing using some scripts. Interaction testing is kind of end-to-end testing using a mocking framework/or mocks creating using hand. If you have no code in your code-behind files, you should be able to do this. Also, I would suggest to use a mocking framework/mock by hand to mock your config files so you have no interaction with the actual files during unit testing.